# Document Association in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

If a Alfresco user selects x number of documents from the current folder and wants to have a parent document where all x documents are attached in a single document and can download it. Should I create a custom web script to perform this or how can association concept be leveraged here. Eg. Lets say a product requirement document, testing and release document needs to be attached together into a single document.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Smart Folders. https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/concepts/sf-whatis.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you mismatch document (download one combined document) and collection (association) concepts.

You could create your own custom document model which supports to logically attach documents to another (master) document by adding an association. You could also define in that model that the attached documents will be stored as a child of the master which will somehow hide the attached documents in the folders. We implemented this concept for our Alfresco Email and our custom Attachment module.

If you need the possibility to download that logical document (which still may be a collection of documents) the easiest way would be to implement a custom action shown up on your master document which will zip the master and all connected documents. If you expect to download only a single document like a PDF you will have to write your custom conversion logic which will convert the single docs into pages and to compose them into a single PDF. This could be sophisticated since the documents could be of any format. Maybe you also want/need to save metadata, process information, decisions, structure also ...